# Spring Data mongoDB : how to fetch one document per name based on date

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongoDB request to perform which initially sounded pretty easy to me but made me sweat a lot for a result I’m not too convinced with.
I searched a lot for similar questions but found none really answering my need.
I’m using Spring Boot framework for my backend.
The objective is rather simple.
I have a collection of documents in database as in the example below:

```
[{“name” : “Bob”,
“contract” : false,
”ranking” : 3,
“timestamp”: 1606867200},
{“name” : “Bob”,
“contract” : true,
”ranking” : 5,
“timestamp”: 1606953600},
{“name” : “Roger”,
“contract” : true,
”ranking” : 25,
“timestamp”: 1607040000},
{“name” : “Bob”,
“contract” : true,
”ranking” : 5,
“timestamp”: 1607040000}]
```

I want to fetch one document per unique name where the timestamp (i.e. the date in epoch milliseconds format) is the highest (so latest date).
So in the example above I would have two results:

```
[{“name” : “Roger”,
“contract” : true,
”ranking” : 25,
“timestamp”: 1607040000},
{“name” : “Bob”,
“contract” : true,
”ranking” : 5,
“timestamp”: 1607040000}]
```

To do this, the only solution I found was to use an Aggreation.
This can be done in Spring using mongoTemplate or as in my case using Aggregation Repository Methods which works fine also [see here for details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.aggregation)

What I want is to fetch one document per name in mongo the document picked for each name being the one with the max timestamp.
This from what I understand is not doable in a straightforward way.
We have to create a new document using the Aggregation pipeline telling him to group based on the names `_id: '$name'` and to pick the highest timestamp : `timestamp: {$max: '$timestamp'}`. However doing so creates a document with only two fields : _ID and timestamp where my POJO in Spring needs (name, contract, ranking, timestamp). The only Way I found to add the rest of the fields was by doing this :

```
String myAggregation = "{ $group: {" +
    "_id: '$name'," +
    "name: {$first: '$name'}," +
    "contract: {$first: '$contract'}," +
    "ranking: {$first: '$ranking'}," +
    "timestamp: {$max: '$timestamp'}," +
    "}}";
// find the latest scan status for each individual UID
@Aggregation(myAggregation)
List<HotlistStatusEntity> findLastStatusOfEachName();
```

But I feel that this could lead to undesired results in some cases with the $first picking the value from a document different than the one where the $max picked its value.
I lack a clear way of explaining my concern but doing what I do, I do not fetch a list of existing documents but recreate documents by picking values "here and there".
Although my tests never lead to unexpected results I’m still not confident with this.
So would there be a more secured or a cleaner way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can sort by name (asc), timestamp(desc). Then, group by name, and get the first document - this will have the highest timestamp and the corresponding document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Doing so however would only fetch one document not a list containing one document per name. But Maybe I got it wrong?